# How to set a login link to unlogged user using else function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Help me please I'm new for php....

the below code is to show the menus for a logged in user. but when user is not logged in then these are not displayed so i want to display a login link for new use using else function with this script.. But i can;t do this. SO please help me right now

```
   <?
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {?>
  <div class="myaccount">
  <p><strong>My Account</strong></p>
  <a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a><br>
  <a href="mysettings.php">Settings</a><br>
  <a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
  <p>You can add more links here for users</p></div>
  <? } ?>
```

Now tell me how i use a login link with this script for a new user.....

Answer (score 3):

Just add this `else` code block after `if`

```
<? else{ ?>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
<? } ?>
```

So, you code should look like this:

```
   <?
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {?>
    <div class="myaccount">
    <p><strong>My Account</strong></p>
    <a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a><br>
    <a href="mysettings.php">Settings</a><br>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
    <p>You can add more links here for users</p></div>
  <? } ?>         <!-- line x -->
  <? else{ ?>     <!-- line y -->
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
  <? } ?>
```

line x and y can be combined to this:

```
<? } else { ?>
```

**EDIT:**

Using the x and y lines combined, your code should look like this:

```
   <?
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {?>
    <div class="myaccount">
    <p><strong>My Account</strong></p>
    <a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a><br>
    <a href="mysettings.php">Settings</a><br>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
    <p>You can add more links here for users</p></div>
  <? } else { ?>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
  <? } ?>
```

Further reading: [PHP: else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php)

Comment: hi..you helped well but i'm still getting a new error   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /home/hdswebco/public_html/index.php on line 24

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /home/hdswebco/public_html/index.php on line 24

Comment: @Manishb510 Please see my edit above. Also make sure to read on `else`. Its very basic about programming that every programmer is expected to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {?>
  <div class="myaccount">
  <p><strong>My Account</strong></p>
  <a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a><br>
  <a href="mysettings.php">Settings</a><br>
  <a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
  <p>You can add more links here for users</p></div>
  <? } else {?>
   Login link here
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
<div class="myaccount">
<?
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {?>
<p><strong>My Account</strong></p>
<a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a><br>
<a href="mysettings.php">Settings</a><br>
<a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
 <? } else {  ?>
<a href="logout.php">Login </a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```